# How to control Tuya API device with an HTML request

Tags: html, automation, cloud, iot, tuya

So I'm trying to make my phone button a light switch. I found an app that can remap my phone's physical buttons to commands. One of them is HTML Request (POST and GET I have no idea any of this).

I figured out how to control my light bulb with a phyton script. I got it working with Tuya API. My first plan was to somehow execute this phyton script on the cloud but I don't know how and I thought it would be a dumb solution because I think we can directly control the device via Tuya that is on the cloud already.

I think HTTP Request can send/post(?) a command to Tuya API to turn my light bulb on/off. Or maybe there's another way to do this? Attached screenshot of the command output list to map my button.

[image: command list]

[image: http request query]

Comment: This turns out harder than I imagine. Because its not as simple sending an HTML Request to the cloud server to control my device. But it need something like authentication for each request and there's a limitation. I have figured another solution, still using Tuya cloud (but instead of openapi.tuyaus.com, I use px1.tuyaus.com/homeassistant). It just need 2 http requests for this simple task, the first one is to get the auth token, then use this auth token to send other command to the device.